# How to specify that test jars are to be fetched/downloaded from maven repository?

Tags: eclipse, gradle, buildship

What is the way to fetch test jars from maven repository? If I wanted to fetch javadocs or sources for a jar in repository, I would put the following in build.gradle file:

```
eclipse {
    classpath {
        downloadJavadoc = true
        downloadSources = true
    }
}
```

Ideally, getting the test jars would require just adding

```
downloadTest = true
```

in the same place, but it doesn’t work that way. So how does one achieve that? For an example of test (and other) jars, see:
[image: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/undertow/undertow-core/2.0.27.Final/]

Answer (score 0):

Reporting solution by Donat Csikos (who deserves all the credit) in [gradle forum](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/eclipse-downloadtest/33823/4):
This is how to get the tests jars in gradle if needed:

```
dependencies {
  implementation("io.undertow:undertow-core:2.0.27.Final:tests")
}
```

buildship eclipse gradle plugin will make it available in eclipse, like any other resource.